# Python Tkinter button with variable class commands

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

Sorry if the title is confusing, I don't really know how to describe what I'm trying to do here. I want to use lambda functions in order get a class method. Basically I want to do this

```
def listButton(frame, ls, command, arg):
    for item in ls:
        // For each item in the list, add a button whose command is a class method of the type of item,
        // the argument of which is another class method of the type of item.
        frame.addButton(item.display(), lambda: item.command(item.arg))
    frame.update()
```

I'm getting an error regarding the fact that the type of item has no attribute "command", which is correct, but I want to substitute in my argument "command" into the item.command.

If this is confusing, I'll provide a use case:

Input

`listButton(frame, listOfItems, lambda arg: print(arg), lambda: display())`

How I'd like the line in question interpreted

```
// For the first iteration of the for loop, for example
frame.addButton(frame, lambda: listOfItems[0].print(listOfItems[0].display()))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no reasonable way to turn a `lambda` containing a function call into a call to a method of the same name the function had.  Your scheme is insanely overcomplicated, yet horribly restrictive: every method you might ever want to call takes exactly one parameter?  And that parameter will only ever come from another method, not a constant or an attribute or any other source of values?  Keep it simple: pass one lambda, that is given an element from your list as its parameter, and *does whatever it needs to do with that object* - `lambda obj: obj.print(obj.display())` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As you said, this will only ever work with one parameter functions - is there a way I can have variable parametrisation of my lambdas and lambda calls?